# Getting the response of a webpage that contains javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

In my C# app i got the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string uri = urlTextBox.Text;

    Uri myURL;

    if (!Uri.TryCreate(uri, UriKind.Absolute, out myURL))
        return;

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(myURL);
    request.Method = "GET";
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                responseTextBox.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

}

But when I click the button it returns me the following text:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Login Timed Out</title>
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="../../shared/css/ilearn_base.css">
<script>
function redirectToTop(reloginLoc) {
   if (opener != null && opener != self) {
      opener.top.location = reloginLoc;
      window.close();
   }

   else if (top != self) {
      top.location = reloginLoc;
   }

   else {
      location = reloginLoc;
   }
}
</script>
<noscript>
Your browser does not support JavaScript. Please turn on JavaScript to use the features of this web page.
</noscript>

</head>
<body onLoad="redirectToTop('../../learner/jsp/relogin_site.jsp')">

</body>
</html>
```

What I can't understand is why it says: "`Your browser does not support JavaScript. Please turn on JavaScript to use the features of this web page.`", because I activated JavaScript in both my current browser and in IE.

In my Internet Browsers the page looks different, having the scripts executed, and I want to find out how can I activate javascript in C# browser to get the full response.

Comment: I suspect what you're actually looking for is a "mock user agent"... something like http://watin.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the full response.

The noscript tags are included in case your browser doesn't support javascript.  For this page the server likely always includes this in the response - it does not necessarily mean that your browser doesn't support javascript.